# How can I reduce an array of objects based on prop name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to turn:

```
  Array(19) [
{ category: 'Entertainment', 'Hang with Friends': 100 }, 
{ category: 'Entertainment', Chill: 30 }, 
{ category: 'Health', Yoga: 40 },
{ category: 'Health', Birthday: 200 }, 
   ]
```

into:

```
  Array(19) [
{ category: 'Entertainment', 'Hang with Friends': 100, Chill: 30 }, 
{ category: 'Health', Yoga: 40, Birthday: 200 },
   ]
```

I attempted to do it using the logic from my last question but that one was reduced based on a prop that was a number, so I could index it. Here, I'm trying to do it based off of the category prop which is a string and can't be used to index.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work at all:

```
  const reducedData = Object.values(newData).reduce(
    (index, { id, category, subCategory, price }) => {
      Object.assign((index[category] ??= category), {
        [subCategory]: price,
      });
      return index;
    },
    {}
  );
```

I want to be able to loop through the other objects in the array to find the obj with the correct category prop but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be great!

Also, I've changed the format to the following because it was mentioned that it's easier to work with. How would you the same to the following?

```
  Array(19) [
{ category: 'Entertainment', subCategory: 'Hang with Friends', price: 100 }, 
{ category: 'Entertainment', subCategory: 'Chill', price: 30 }, 
{ category: 'Health', subCategory: 'Yoga', price: 40 },
{ category: 'Health', subCategory: 'Birthday', price: 200 }, 
   ]
```

Comment: This probably isn't helpful, but both of those formats seem difficult to work with, if you have a choice I'd suggest going for something like `{category: 'Health', activity: 'Yoga', score: 40}` so each object has consistent properties.

Comment: Okay, that's no problem. If the format was like that, do you know what the answer would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object that stores the merged object using the category as the key.

```js
const arr=[{category:"Entertainment","Hang with Friends":100},{category:"Entertainment",Chill:30},{category:"Health",Yoga:40},{category:"Health",Birthday:200},];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr) =>
  (Object.assign(acc[curr.category] ??= {}, curr), acc), {}));
console.log(res);
```

You can use a type assertion for the accumulator in TypeScript:

```
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr) =>
 (Object.assign(acc[curr.category] ??= {}, curr), acc), {} as Record<string, unknown>));
```

Or you can set the generic type parameter for `reduce`:

```
arr.reduce<Record<string, unknown>>(...)
```

Comment: Same issue, I can't use a string to index an array, acc[curr.category] breaks the code

Comment: @Mathew You could add `{} as Record<string, unknown>` to the accumulator.

Comment: I'm still a little confused however, could you explain what this line is doing? (Object.assign((acc[curr.category] ??= {}), curr), acc), you're assigning acc[curr.category] to an empty obj if it doesnt exist and if it does, assigning it curr?

Comment: @Mathew First, it sets `acc[curr.category]` to an empty object if it is currently undefined (or null). Then, it merges the value of `acc[curr.category]` with the `curr` object (which is what `Object.assign` does).

Comment: What's 'acc' doing at the end there? (Object.assign((acc[curr.category] ??= {}), curr), ***acc***)

Comment: @Mathew It's returning the accumulator so we don't lose access to it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator

Comment: Ah okay, I haven't seen that notation yet, thanks! So it's doing the same thing as: newData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      Object.assign((acc[curr.category] ??= {}), curr);
      return acc;
    }, {} as Record<string, unknown>)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{
    category: 'Entertainment',
    'Hang with Friends': 100
  },
  {
    category: 'Entertainment',
    Chill: 30
  },
  {
    category: 'Health',
    Yoga: 40
  },
  {
    category: 'Health',
    Birthday: 200,
  },
];

let data1 = arr.map(({
  category
}) => category);

let data2 = [];
arr.forEach((e, index, arr) => {
  if (data1.includes(e.category, index + 1)) {
    data2.push({ ...e,
      ...arr[index + 1]
    })
  }

});
console.log(data2);
```